# Move a system from LVM to standard partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, lvm

I need to move a system which uses LVM to a system which uses normal partitions.
I created the partitions on the new hard drive and I copied all the content of the root and boot partition to the new hard drive.

Finally I modified `fstab` and reinstalled `grub`, but if I try to boot the system I see the error:

> System no longer boots, gave up waiting for root device, (initramfs),
>   /dev/mapper/OLD_LVM_VOLUME_NAME-root does not exist

Moreover, if I use the `initramfs` prompt I do not find any `/dev/sd*` device, even if I am sure that there should be a `/dev/sda1` (it exists as expected from a live cd).

How can I remove all the references to the old LVM volume and boot using `/dev/sda1` as a root partition?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to run `update-grub`.  Press `e` at the grub menu to edit the entry and change the root= argument to point to the right place ( /dev/sda1 ), and you should be able to boot once.  Then run `update-grub` to update the menu with the correct location for future boots.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit `/etc/fstab` to point to the proper root (and other partitions) and update grub.

See

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

If you have a problem, post your partition scheme and /etc/fstab

To re-install grub,

```
sudo grub-install
```