# Moving root from LVM to standard ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm, ext4

I'm on a server with Ubuntu 18.04LTS with single disk in LVM partition. Boot partition is ext2 , root partition is ext4 in volume group beta-root (as show below)

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  798M  3.3M  795M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/beta-root  293G  129G  152G  46% /
tmpfs                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                  512M     0  512M   0% /clam-tmp
/dev/sda1              228M  111M  106M  52% /boot
tmpfs                  798M     0  798M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs                  798M     0  798M   0% /run/user/0


Disk /dev/sda: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000456c7

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    499711    497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2          501758 125827071 125325314 59.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       125827072 629145599 503318528  240G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda5          501760 125827071 125325312 59.8G 8e Linux LVM

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/beta-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,acl 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9b35bbcc-61f6-410a-bc43-f06516bfedd6 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/beta-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0

tmpfs   /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults,noexec,nosuid  0       0

tmpfs /clam-tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=512M 0 0
```

There's an understandable method to migrate full system from a mixed environment (LVM and non-LVM) to a new hard disk (let's say /dev/sdb) with same layout but with no LVM at all?

Thanks for support!

Comment: have you tried rsync or cp to move the data? `man rsync`... if all your data is mounted and accessible syncing it to another drive should be trivial... even something as simple as `cp -R /mnt/LVM/* /mnt/SDB/` then rsync the rest of your data to /mnt/SDB (I don't know how to do this off of the top of my head.. I need to look) then you could use something like boot-repair to make that drive bootable... anyone have any other thoughts on this?

Comment: Oh, and welcome to AskUbuntu! Nice first question!

Comment: rsyncing while system is live is not a good idea I suppose (MySQL, Apache, ...) write on system, even logs do the same... I suppose that could be done if you run to a lower init level like init 1 , but don't know if that is enough.

Comment: ah, thx for welcome ^^

Comment: found similar question here, but it's a dead thread and non-significant answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/439987/move-a-system-from-lvm-to-standard-partitions

Comment: You could get around this by booting to a LiveUSB... Then you could run the boot-repair from the liveusb environment so set up your new drive for booting...

Answer (score 6):

The steps I would follow, in a nutshell, are as thus:

1. Boot from a [liveUSB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
2. Install [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   ```
3. Install and mount LVM drives as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
   sudo apt-get install lvm2   #This step may or may not be required.
   sudo pvscan                 #Use this to verify your LVM partition(s) is/are detected.
   sudo vgscan                 #Scans for LVM Volume Group(s)
   sudo vgchange -ay           #Activates LVM Volume Group(s)
   sudo lvscan                 #Scans for available Logical Volumes
   sudo mount /dev/YourVolGroup00/YourLogVol00 /YourMountPoint
   ```
4. Mount the drive where you are moving the data
5. Copy data from the old to the new drive:

   Copy the boot partition:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4096
   ```

   Copy the root partition:¹

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/beta/root | pv -s 300G | dd of=/dev/sdb2 bs=4096
   ```
6. [Run Boot-Repair on the new drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Using_Boot-Repair):

   ```
   sudo boot-repair
   ```
7. Reboot

<sub>**Note 1:** This could take a *very* long time.</sub>

Comment: you've anticipated me ;)

I've wrote something similar below, but it seems we're on the same wave of ideas.

I've cloned that server (is a vmware esx machine, not a problem) , tomorrow I'll give a shot on that clone doing something similar and I'll report some feedback!

Comment: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common is needed before

Comment: installing pv with sudo apt install pv 
partitioning /dev/sdb1 500MB and /dev/sdb2 remaining space now I can issue

# COPY BOOT PARTITION
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4096

# COPY ROOT PARTITION
sudo dd if=/dev/beta/root | pv -s 300G | dd of=/dev/sdb2 bs=4096

next step is to fix boot with boot repair... but dd says it tooks more than 8hours... good night :)

Comment: excellent! glad things are going! anyway, I added info from your comment to the answer..  feel free to edit the answer to add any relevant info (it will earn you rep points too)

Comment: I just realized you will also need to edit your /etc/fstab to point to your new drives as well as deleting the old ones... can you post a copy of your /etc/fstab to your question so we can make a new one to put into the answer? thanks :)

Comment: Hi there Joshua, done some arrangement to previous post adding some notes and edited first post adding fstab output. Yesterday night maybe I was a little bit tired.. tried to dd a 300GB partition on a 150GB destination... lol. Started new process this morning with a similar destination layout. DD is ongoing...

Comment: An edit *and* an upvote!  **;-)**  Please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1164398/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)** (E.G. when numbering and providing code, use 8 spaces to indent)  **0:-)**